# Hive : java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'metastore.dbs' doesn't exist

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hive

I am using hive version : 3.2.1
and hadoop version : 3.2.1
and database for metastore : mysql

when trying to run hive in debug mode :

```
$hive -hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```

I am getting the error

```
metastore.dbs table does not exists.

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'metastore.dbs' doesn't exist
```

below is the snippted of my hive-site.xml

```
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
#<value>jdbc:derby:;databaseName=metastore_db;create=true</value>
 <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>
  JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
  To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide database-specific SSL flag in the connection URL.
  For example, jdbc:postgresql://myhost/db?ssl=true for postgres database.
</description>
</property>
```

Please help in resolving the error.

Comment: can you connect without DEBUG mode? If yes, then this may be DEBUG related issue

Comment: Yes, it gets connected without debug mode as well, the reason I am unsing debug mode is - I can see the error stack trace.

Comment: This seems like to me a generic error. I think your `hive-log4j.properties` is not properly set or absent. If absent, please check below link to create a properties file in your home folder and use it to debug. Please refer to answer #2 
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854359/how-to-run-hive-in-debug-mode

Comment: the reason I am using the debug mode is because I am getting error when querying into the hive : hive> show tables;
FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Comment: Did you `-initSchema`? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Schema+Tool

Comment: No I didn’t do initschema, let me try that in tomorrow morning, I guess this might help

Comment: Hey @mazaneicha, schematool -dbType mysql -initSchema worked. Thanks for your help